# Salesforce b2b commerce CMS

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

Is there any way we can get the URL of an image uploaded in the CMS workspace so that we can make use of it in the experience site?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the image which you inserted in the CMS workspace and copy the image address. In this way, you will image get the image address.

Thanks!!!